# jQuery/jQueryUI Droppable take the shape of Draggable

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a single column table, where every cell is a droppable that accepts draggables of a certain class. The borders of this table are visible, but I do not want fixed size cells coloured and visible, which looks ugly to me. When I drag a draggable to intersection with a cell, the cell would highlight, which is not difficult to do, but I also want this highlight to take the size of the draggable. All draggables are fixed width, but some have more height than others, so adapting the height would be sufficient, but I have no idea where to begin. [Here](http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/127_iNETTUTS/demo/index.html) is an example of the kind of adaptation I am looking for.

Comment: i am making a wild guess at your problem, but i need to see some code to understand. can you provide your code, or depict it in a jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, I recommend that you use jQueryUI "Sortable" instead of Draggable/Droppable.
See the  [portlets demo on the jQueryUI site](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets) , it should be the functionality you're looking for.

**Edit**: @Subhamoy, I see now what you mean.
Here is a solution that uses Sortable and relies on CSS to build the table:
[Link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/LVyuu/3/)

The key part is the 'over' handler that takes care of resizing the placeholder:

```
$( ".target .tbody" ).sortable({
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    placeHolder: "ui-sortable-placeholder",
    connectWith: ".source .tbody",
    items: "> .tr",
    over: function(event, ui) {
        var $context = $(this)
            ,$h = ui.helper
            ,$p = $('.ui-sortable-placeholder', $context)
            ,hheight = $h.height()
        ;
        $p.removeAttr("style");
        $p.css("height", hheight + "px");
    }
});
```

Comment: I do not see how, because no matter what the height of the draggable is, the droppable area outlined is always the same.

Comment: @SubhamoySengupta, I've linked to a jsfiddle that will hopefully match your requirement.

Comment: This is fantastic and exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much and my apologies for taking so long to accept it. I have a side question. Can this work with one header or footer cell fixed and the columns not being sortable, so that adding to the droppable column only happens at the bottom and not in random locations?

Comment: Regarding your side question: Do you mean soemthing like:
    http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/LVyuu/4/
 ?

Comment: Not exactly. After you drop a draggable, you can drop another draggable above it. Adding should happen only from bottom. This is happening because they are sortable, I guess.